# translation not working in Django 1.5 even after compiling message

Tags: django, django-1.5

I'm using **Django 1.5**

I have to enable internationalization in my application. For that, I have added a few things to the settings.py file

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)

from django.conf import global_settings
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    '...local context processrors...'
)

# global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS contains 
# TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
#     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
#     'django.core.context_processors.debug',
#     'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
#     ...
# )

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

# List of languages available for translation
ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('es', ugettext('Spanish'))
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'locale/'),
)
```

The LOCALE_PATHS has the location output as

```
('/media/path_to_project/workbench/workbench/settings/../locale/',)
```

But on running `./manage.py makemessages -l es` it generates *.po file in

```
/media/path_to_project/workbench/workbench
```

instead of

```
/media/path_to_project/workbench/workbench/locale
```

Also, the compiled language is not showing in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check following things.

- Ensure that you added `USE_L10N = True` and `USE_I18N = True` into your `settings.py` file
- Check for `PROJECT_ROOT` and `LOCALE_PATHS` and make sure that it is correct
- Add `django.core.context_processors.i18n` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in `setting.py`.

> Translation and formatting are controlled by **USE_I18N** and **USE_L10N** settings respectively. However, both features involve **internationalization** and **localization**. The names of the settings are an unfortunate result of Django’s history.

Comment: Everything is configured properly. `USE_I18N=True` is in settings.py and `django.core.context_processors.i18n` is already imported from global settings of `django.conf`.

Comment: Could you share `settings.py` file to me?

Comment: have updated question with translation related stuffs in the settings.py file

Comment: What is `PROJECT_ROOT`?

Comment: `'/media/path_to_project/workbench/workbench/settings/../'`

Comment: It works by moving `locale` files from `conf/locale` to the `LOCALE_PATHS` works. But why files not generating at the right place with `makemessages` command?